# How to display the value of each variable in bar with plot() with "group_by" dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I generated a bar plot, where I grouped 2 variables in a single bar: --> [as is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hvNW.png)

1. how can I display the value of the individual variables in each bar?
2. how can I display the value of the total for each bar??

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No","Yes", "No"], 'col2': ["Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High","High", "Medium"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_grouped = df.groupby('col2')['col1'].value_counts(normalize=False).unstack()
df_grouped.plot(kind="bar", alpha=1, stacked='False', figsize=(14, 8))
```

Instead, this would be my goal: --> [to-be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2Cwg.png)

I did some research but I didn't find anything useful for my purpose.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "No","Yes", "No"], 'col2': ["Low", "Medium", "Medium", "High","High", "Medium"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_grouped = df.groupby('col2')['col1'].value_counts(normalize=False).unstack()
df_grouped.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

---

```
ax = df_grouped.plot(kind='bar',width=0.8,stacked=True,figsize=(14,9))
list_values = df_grouped.values.flatten()
gr_values = np.sum(df_grouped.values, axis=1)

list_values = df_grouped.values.flatten('F')
for i, (rect, value) in enumerate(zip(ax.patches, list_values)):
    if value != 0:
        h = rect.get_height() /2.
        w = rect.get_width() /2.
        x, y = rect.get_xy()
        ax.text(x+w, y+h,value,horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center', weight='bold')
        ax.text(x+w,gr_values[i%len(gr_values)]*1.03,gr_values[i%len(gr_values)],horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='center',  weight='bold')
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: This shows number in float but you can change it to int either by changing all the df columns as int or in text convert the number to int format